# REGEXP_SUBSTR function in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Please help me resolve PLS-00103 error for this stored procedure:

```
'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORTS_MV."Custom_Report" (l_cursor OUT sys_refcursor) AS v_sql CLOB; 
BEGIN 
v_sql := 'SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.DISTRICT_NUMBER, '[^-]+') AS "District Number", REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.DISTRICT_NUMBER, '[^-]+', 1, 2) AS "District Name", REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.TERRITORY_NUMBER, '[^-]+') AS "Territory Number", REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.TERRITORY_NUMBER, '[^-]+', 1, 2) AS "Territory Name"';

 v_sql := v_sql || ' FROM REPORTS_MV."STAGE-EMDEON_REDEMPTION" A ' || ' LEFT JOIN REPORTS_MV."STAGE-CARD_GROUP" CG ON A.GROUP_NUMBER = CG.GROUP_NUMBER'; 

v_sql := v_sql || ' LEFT JOIN REPORTS_MV."STAGE-ZIP2TERRITORY" Z2T' 
|| ' ON CG.ORGANIZATION_KEY = Z2T.ORGANIZATION_KEY'; 

v_sql := v_sql || ' ORDER BY A.GROUP_NUMBER, A.RECEIVED_DATE '; 
--dbms_output.put_line (v_sql); 
OPEN l_cursor FOR v_sql; END; /'
```

Error

> PLS-00103 (40: 53): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "[" when expecting one of the following:
>
> - & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
>      <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4

Comment: Thanks XYZ.  It appears there are nested single-quotes within the v_sql string literal.  Effectively the string ends and is followed by a [ symbol, which won't compile.  You can fix by escaping them or by using alternative quoted literals.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00220

Comment: @alexgibbs Would you be abe to edit my store procedure to get this right for me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't of course say whether the dynamic sql is executable as written, but using *alternative-quoting* or *escaping* should allow this to compile.

The example below uses q-quoting to allow for single-quotes within the string literal.  The Oracle documentation on Literals has much more information on the topic.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORTS_MV.CUSTOM_REPORT(L_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
    V_SQL CLOB;
BEGIN
    V_SQL := Q'!SELECT
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.DISTRICT_NUMBER, '[^-]+') AS "District Number",
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.DISTRICT_NUMBER, '[^-]+', 1, 2) AS "District Name",
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.TERRITORY_NUMBER, '[^-]+') AS "Territory Number",
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(Z2T.TERRITORY_NUMBER, '[^-]+', 1, 2) AS "Territory Name"
        FROM REPORTS_MV."STAGE-EMDEON_REDEMPTION" A
        LEFT JOIN REPORTS_MV."STAGE-CARD_GROUP" CG ON A.GROUP_NUMBER = CG.GROUP_NUMBER
        LEFT JOIN REPORTS_MV."STAGE-ZIP2TERRITORY" Z2T
        ON CG.ORGANIZATION_KEY = Z2T.ORGANIZATION_KEY
        ORDER BY A.GROUP_NUMBER, A.RECEIVED_DATE!';
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_SQL);
    OPEN L_CURSOR FOR V_SQL;
END;
/
```